# what's the output format of 'find . -ls'?

Tags: linux, find

I'm looking at the output of `find . -ls`. For example, here is a small excerpt for `/lib64` on a CentOS system:

```
163542   28 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     root        28448 Aug  4  2010 ./libvolume_id.so.0.66.0
163423    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           16 Mar  3  2010 ./libwrap.so.0 -> libwrap.so.0.7.6
163601    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           11 Nov  9  2010 ./libc.so.6 -> libc-2.5.so
```

The find(1) man page says "list current file in `ls -dils` format on standard output". I then tried to figure it out from ls(1) man page, but I'm stumped on the second column.  Any idea?

For reference: the columns (with ref. for the first line) are:

1. `inode 163542`
2. `???   28` *what is this? `stat` that file doesn't mention any field equals to '28'*
3. `permissions  -rwxr-xr-x`
4. `hard-links   1`
5. `owner root`
6. `group root`
7. `size(bytes) 28448`
8. `modified Aug  4  2010`
9. `name ./libvolume_id.so.0.66.0`
10. (for logical links: `-> softlink`)

Comment: That second column is the block size that you get from `ls -s`. See [file block size - difference between stat and ls](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28780/file-block-size-difference-between-stat-and-ls) and perhaps also [What does size of a directory mean in output of 'ls -l' command?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-does-size-of-a-directory-mean-in-output-of-ls-l-command)

Comment: @Oded et.al: may I respectfully ask what is wrong with this question?

Comment: The question was considered off-topic because it isn't clearly programming related. Kev suggested migrating to [unix.se]; I said not to migrate because I think it would be a duplicate of the question I cited.

Answer (score 3):

Doh, a casual regression against size reveals that it's roughly the number of 1024-byte blocks...